# Symfony formbuilder - input name as array

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I just want want this output for my input:

```
<input name="aFilter[id..][brand][]"> ...
```

Now i don't get this aFilter[id..] dynamicly.

Here is my try

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')
        ->createNamedBuilder('aFilter[\'test\']', 'form')
```

Is there a way to get this solved with formbuilder?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think the process you follow to take the html input is in wrong format. I will suggest you to follow the link....
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html
......I hope you do.